# Dingo Api registering in RouteServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes, dingo-api

I've read that it's possible to specify namespace for Dingo in that way

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', ['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($api) {
   $api->get('sites', 'SiteController@index');
   $api->get('sites/{site}', 'SiteController@show');
   $api->post('sites', 'SiteController@store');
   $api->put('sites/{site}', 'SiteController@update');
   $api->delete('sites/{site}', 'SiteController@delete');
});
```

However, I've got multiple files with API routes so that I don't want to mess it with namespace and would like to specify namespace in Laravel way like that

```
protected function mapDingoApiRoutes() {
        Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'api',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        ], function ($api) {
            require base_path('routes/api/sites.api.php');
            require base_path('routes/api/skills.api.php');
            require base_path('routes/api/socials.api.php');
        });
    }
```

However it turned out that Dingo doesn't see this namespace declaration and I'm not able to make something like `$api->group()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved that way

```
...
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Router;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
...

public function map()
    {
        $this->mapDingoApiRoutes(app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router'));

        $this->mapWebRoutes();
    }

protected function mapDingoApiRoutes(Router $api) {
        $api->group([
            'version' => 1,
            'middleware' => 'api',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        ], function ($api) {
            require base_path('routes/api/sites.api.php');
            require base_path('routes/api/skills.api.php');
            require base_path('routes/api/socials.api.php');
        });
    }

...
}
```